# Как создать объект фрагмента из другого класса

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragment, context

Как создать объект класса фрагмента.
Например, чтобы создать объект класса активии надо провернуть такое:

```
MainActivity mainActivity = (MainActivity)context;
```

Как сделать тоже самое подобное, только с классом фрагмента?
Это не прокатывает:

```
MyFragment myFragment = (MyFragment)context;
```

Answer (score 3):

То что вы делаете, называется приведением типа, а не созданием объекта фрагмента.

Объекты создаются с помощью ключевого слова `new`
Пример `MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment()`

Строка `MyFragment myFragment = (MyFragment)context;` вообще не имеет смысла, т.к. фрагмент не является контекстом. (А активити является, но это тоже не совсем корректно. Активити это ContextWrapper но приводится к типу Context)